# Why am I getting an exception as I try to parse .docx file?

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx

While trying to read a `.docx` file I am get the following exception :

```
org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.OfficeXmlFileException: The supplied data
appears to be in the Office 2007+ XML. You are calling the part of POI 
that deals with OLE2 Office Documents. You need to call a different part of POI
to process this data (eg XSSF instead of HSSF)

at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlock.<init>(HeaderBlock.java:131)
at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlock.<init>(HeaderBlock.java:104)
at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem.<init>(POIFSFileSystem.java:128)
at org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocumentCore.verifyAndBuildPOIFS(HWPFDocumentCore.java:106)
at org.apache.poi.hwpf.extractor.WordExtractor.<init>(WordExtractor.java:53)
at org.suhail.gui.Main.parseDocxFile(Main.java:245)
at org.suhail.gui.Main.jButton1ActionPerformed(Main.java:166)
at org.suhail.gui.Main.access$000(Main.java:21)
at org.suhail.gui.Main$1.actionPerformed(Main.java:70)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6038)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3260)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:5803)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2058)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4410)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2116)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4240)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4322)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:3986)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:3916)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2102)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2429)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4240)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:273)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:183)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:173)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:168)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:160)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:121)
```

I do get an idea of what could be the reason for the exception but don't exactly understand the reason.

The `.docx` file saved is from a `2007 MS Word` software.

Snippet that is parsing the file :

```
public void parseDocxFile(String textEntered) {
    try {
        WordExtractor extractor = new WordExtractor(new FileInputStream(new File(SContainer.getFilePath())));
        System.out.println(".DOCX File : " + extractor.getText());
    }catch(Exception exc) {exc.printStackTrace();}
}
```

*Note: I am using the latest version of POI 3.10*

Answer (score 4):

As per Apache POI [docs](http://poi.apache.org/document/index.html) for docx you have to use XWPF not HWPF apis.

> HWPF is the name of our port of the Microsoft Word 97(-2007) file
>   format to pure Java. It also provides limited read only support for
>   the older Word 6 and Word 95 file formats.
>        The partner to HWPF for the new Word 2007 .docx format is XWPF

use [XWPF apis](http://poi.apache.org/document/quick-guide-xwpf.html) to read docx file.

> For basic text extraction, make use of
>   org.apache.poi.xwpf.extractor.XWPFWordExtractor. It accepts an input
>   stream or a XWPFDocument. The getText() method can be used to get the
>   text from all the paragraphs, along with tables, headers etc.

UPDATED:
 To address your question.

```
 What is the difference between the two ?
```

Let me try to address IMO . .doc format is binary obfuscated document format , which required  third party support to read those documents, so the HWPF uses third party support to implement  But from 2007 Microsoft uses the OOXML (Office Object eXtended Markup Language) , which is publicly available thus to implement API to read this format become easier .  So Apache implemented another set of API to read OOXMl format files ( .docx) .

HWPF and XWPF does not share any common interface / methods / code. both are independent.

And i found this [link](http://developeriq.in/articles/2012/jul/03/handling-ms-word-documents-using-apache-poi/) Provides samples using both the framework. It may useful.

Comment: What is the difference between the two ?